# What different between object created from initialization constructor and assign operator?

Tags: c++, c++11

Compiler is GCC 4.8.4 with -std=c++11 flag assigned.

I've got a compile error while compiling a very sample project.

```
ifstream f(this->pid_file_name());
string content(istreambuf_iterator<char>(f), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
pid_t pid = stoi(content);
```

It will pop up error like this :

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘stoi(std::string (&)(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)()))’
     pid_t pid = stoi(content);
```

However, if I change string declaration like this, every things goes fine :

```
ifstream f(this->pid_file_name());
string content = string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(f), istreambuf_iterator<char>());

pid_t pid = stoi(content);
```

I know there are differents by the way how we create a object instance, but I think they should be the same, I have no idea why initialization constructor can't work. Do anyone have idea on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a function declaration:

```
string content(istreambuf_iterator<char>(f), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

See [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

One way to fix it is to use universal initialization syntax:

```
string content{istreambuf_iterator<char>(f), istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
```

Comment: Ah, looks like I have asked a really dumb question :( Thanks for figuring out this.

Comment: No problem. I was actually surprised that exactly the same question was asked before.