# operator= doesn't work properly in my custom string class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, explicit-conversion

I'm trying to create a custom string class using std::vector< char >.

Please take a look at my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class mString {

public:

    mString();
    explicit mString(const char *str);
    mString(const mString &str);

    mString operator=(const char *str);

private:

    typedef std::vector<char> vecChar;
    vecChar _vc;
};

inline mString::mString(){}
inline mString::mString(const char *str) {

    const vecChar::size_type size = strlen(str);
    _vc = vecChar(str, str + size);
}
inline mString::mString(const mString &str) {

    _vc = str._vc;
}

inline mString mString::operator=(const char *str) {

    const vecChar::size_type size = strlen(str);
    _vc = vecChar(str, str + size);
    return *this;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    /* This works */
    mString a;
    a = "Hello World";

    /* Error : No viable conversion from 'const char[12]' to mString */
    mString b = "Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why 'mString b = "Hello World";' doesn't work while 'mString a; a= "Hello World";' works.
What do I need to do in order to make it work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"...doesn't work..._" is not a question. You need to tell us how it does not work.

Comment: Not a duplicate of [What different between object created from initialization constructor and assign operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167580/what-different-between-object-created-from-initialization-constructor-and-assign). The question is the same but the answer is different. The line `mString b = "..."` is not an assignment operator. It is an initializing constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing common with the assignment operator.

You declared this constructor

```
explicit mString(const char *str);
```

with the function specifier `explicit`.

Thus in this declaration

```
mString b = "Hello World";
```

the constructor can not be called to convert the string literal `"Hello World"`to an object of the type `mString`.

Remove the function specifier `explicit` and the declaration will compile.

Or instead of the copy initialization as in the declaration above you could use the direct initialization like

```
mString b( "Hello World" );
```

So in this declaration

```
mString b = "Hello World";
```

there are used constructors. But in this expression statement

```
a= "Hello World";
```

there is indeed used the assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you so much!